# Propagate a generic type hint starting at the base class

Tags: python, python-typing

I know that I can have a generic parent class and child class, like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')


class Parent(Generic[T]):
    member_x: T


class Child1(Parent[T]):
    pass
```

Now let's say I have many child classes, `Child2`, `Child3`, etc, which all inherit from `Parent[T]`. Inside of my_module.py, I can give them all typing information like this:

```py
# my_module.py
from project.my_types import Child1, Child2, Child3

T = float

obj1 = Child1[T]()
obj1.member_x = 1  # no typecheck error

obj2 = Child2[T]()
obj2.member_x = 2  # no typecheck error

obj3 = Child3[T]()
obj3.member_x = '3'  # typecheck error!!
```

But what I would like to do is tell the type checker that in my_module, ALL of the instances that are from child classes of `Parent` should have `member_x` the type, `float`, and then just write the code ignoring typing syntax after that, like so:

```py
# my_module.py
from project.my_types import Parent, Child1, Child2, Child3

# incantation goes here informing type checker that the type T for Parent and all its children is `float`

obj1 = Child1()
obj1.member_x = 1  # no typecheck error

obj2 = Child2()
obj2.member_x = 2  # no typecheck error

obj3 = Child3()
obj3.member_x = '3'  # typecheck error!!
```

Can I do it?

Comment: Why not just subclass? `class FloatChild1(Child1[float]): pass`, and then use `FloatChild1` instead. It's both explicit and short.

Comment: you could alternatively use a type alias `Foo = Child[float]` then use `Foo`

Comment: @joel These are both good suggestions and comport with the [suggested approach I received on the typing project Discussion](https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/1428).

Answer (score 0):

I cross-posted this question to Discuss at the typing project, and received [this answer](https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/1428#discussioncomment-6364403), which I think is a concise and good one (and is consistent with the comments received here):

> That seems extremely specific and unusual and I don't think any type system would provide a feature to do this.
>
> The closest you can come is writing a child class `class IntParent(Parent[float])` and inheriting all your child classes from it.

It makes sense to me that what I'm trying to do here isn't something you'd do in most typing applications, and naturally there isn't a built-in solution for doing it.